# Need to authenticate SMAL2 SSO Login with Python Requests

Tags: rest, api, python-requests, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I want to login to the website http://ping.xxx.com/. It redirects to the website https://fedauth.xxx.com/idp/SSO.saml2 where I need to enter my credentials. I am finding it very hard as there is no direct method to authenticate using python requests since it is SAML2 based authentication. Please help in achieving this through Python.

```
import requests
url = 'http://ping.xxx.com/'
values = {'username': 'xxxx',
          'password': 'yyyy'}
with requests.Session() as s:
  p = s.post(url, data=values)
  print (p.url)
```

Comment: It requires several steps, but should be possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Klaus,

I just started. I had written the below code so far

import requests
url = 'http://ping.xxx.com/'
values = {'username': 'xxxx',
          'password': 'yyyy'}
with requests.Session() as s:
  p = s.post(url, data=values)
  print (p.url)


It returns only the url as assigned instead of returning the redirected SSO url

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Hi Klaus, I have updated the post. pls look into it.

Comment: Hi Klaus. Any update?

Comment: @rajasekaranrj, did you get it working? I am also struggling to authenticate on SAML SSO using the Python Requests library.